# Roots of random polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

Assume $P(x)$ is a random polynomial of degree $d$, where its coefficients are picked uniformly at random from $\mathbb{F}_p$, and $p$ is a large prime number. So the polynomial is defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

**Question** 1: What is the probability that polynomial $P(x)$ has at least one root?

**Question** 2: Are roots of $P(x)$ random values in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Could you give a bit of context?

Comment: Useful(?) fact : there are $\frac 1n \sum_{d|n} p^d\mu(\frac nd)$ irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $F_p$. Here $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

Comment: Good question. I'll favorite it, hope to have a nice answer

Comment: I would say that the second question is true, because $P(x)$ and $P(x-x_0)$ for some $x_0$ should be indistinguishable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The reason why I avoided giving more context was to keep it simple. Please see my following comments. In [1], it is said that  $P(x)=R_1.f_1+R_2+f_2$ is a random polynomial where $R_i$ are random polynomials of degree $d$ and $f_i$ are arbitrary polynomials of degree $d$ too. The above approach is used to compute the intersection of two sets (each encoded as polynomial $f_i$). However, this approach introduces some error roots to the result (i.e. elements that are not encoded in $f_i$ but appear in the root of P(x)) . The reason is the use of random polynomials.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Continue: I'd like to build a more efficient mechanism to distinguish the error roots from the actual ones. I realized that if I can give some probability to the occurrence of error roots (rather than considering them as arbitrary values) then I might be able to have a more efficient mechanism than the one used in [1]. 

[1]: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~leak/papers/set-tech-full.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Given $x \in \mathbb F_p$, the probability that a random polynomial of degree $d$ has $x$ as a root is $1/p$.  Thus the expected number of roots of a random polynomial is $1$.  Unfortunately these events are not independent, but we may speculate that for large $d$ and $p$ the number of roots is not too badly approximated by a Poisson distribution, which would say the probability of no roots is approximately $1/e$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why this probability is $\frac 1p$ ?

Comment: Write the polynomial as $P(x) = \sum_{j=0}^d a_j x^j$.  For any $x$ and any $a_1,\ldots,a_d$, there is exactly one value of $a_0$ that makes $P(x) = 0$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please clarify which part of your answer is related to which part of my question. Thanks again!

Comment: What precisely do you mean by question 2?  They are random in the sense that each member of $\mathbb F_p$ has the same probability $1/p$ of being a root.  The rest of the answer is related to question 1.

Comment: For what it's worth, this speculation is right: the distribution limits to Poisson (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11006-006-0139-y.pdf).